# Yii2 impossible to connect to postgresql

Tags: php, database, postgresql, pdo, yii2

I get this error when i'am using yii2 with a postgresql database.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I configured the file main-local.php like this :

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=dbname',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

By the way when i use mysql it's working .

Comment: check the output of `http://localhost/requirements.php` ([docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#verifying-installation)) and see if **PDO PostgreSQL extension** is installed in your server.

Comment: also try `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I did that but i get the same error

Comment: ok check then your `php.ini` file (or `phpinfo()`) and find PostgreSQL sockets paths to see if they are correctly set. I don't know much about PostgreSQL but with MySQL they look like: `mysql.default_socket= /tmp/mysql.sock`, `mysqli.default_socket= /tmp/mysql.sock` and `pdo_mysql.default_socket= /tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: there is no socket section or comment in php.ini for postgresql

Comment: sorry I never used PostgreSQL before. it just looks to me like a wrong DB configuration. see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664903/drupal-7-configuration-error-with-postgresql-in-mac-os-10-6-5) or [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75214/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory) are similar issues to yours.

Answer (score 4):

This is obviously a configuration problem.

1. Call the [requirements page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#verifying-installation) provided by yii2 and check if the **PDO Postgresql** extension is installed.
2. Get your config right. PostgreSQL is different to MySQL. Every Database Cluster contains at least one named *database*. A database contains at least one named *schema* which in turn contain tables.

With that knowledge, your main-local.php should look like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=YOURDATABASE',
            'username' => 'YOURPOSTGRESUSERNAME',
            'password' => 'YOURPOSTGRESPASSWORD',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'schemaMap' => [
                'pgsql' => [
                  'class' => 'yii\db\pgsql\Schema',
                  'defaultSchema' => 'public' //specify your schema here, public is the default schema
                ]
            ], // PostgreSQL
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```